# Can I detect if app is running in Kid's Zone?

Tags: c#, windows-phone, windows-phone-8

I am trying to figure out if it is possible to detect if the app is running in the Kids Zone of Windows Phone 8.

I am having a dialog popup when trying to create a secondary tile that says "When you're in Kid's corner, you can't change what's pinned to start."  I want to disable this menu item if it is in the Kid's Zone so this isn't experienced by any children using my app.

---

Resolved:

The **ApplicationProfile.Modes** property in Windows.Phone.ApplicationModel namespace returns a ApplicationProfileModes object. I used the code below and had the dialog popup and say "Default" in the normal screen and "Alternate" in kids mode.

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnNavigatedTo(e);
    MessageBox.Show(messageBoxText: ApplicationProfile.Modes.ToString());
}
```

**Thank you matthijs Hoekstra for your correct answer.**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can check http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/windows.phone.applicationmodel.applicationprofile.modes(v=vs.105).aspx

Windows.Phone.ApplicationModel.ApplicationProfile namespace

Answer (score 0):

I don't currently know any way to access the starting point of an app.  This would be the information necessary to know if the user was in Kids Corner or not.

Comment: Could it be possible to access the list of apps allowed in the kids corner? maybe that's a place to look?